# Writing a regex that determines the number of matches and extracts desired string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a **number** from a string that should consist of a **number**, a **blank**, and a **word**.

Typically, that string should look like **4 tickets**. (Or maybe "billets 2".)

In other words, the string SHOULD contain a number of 1 to 3 digits, a space, and a word or phrase of some kind. All I care about is the number, the value of the word or what language it is in is completely irrelevant.

I need that number for another part of my code. It is being passed as a string so there's no concern about turning it into an int but I could do that anyway if I needed to using standard idioms.

For safety sake, I think my code should verify that there is just ONE number (regardless of the number of digits in the number) just in case the input is " 4 tickets billets 2" or something crazy like that.

How do I verify that there is exactly 1 number (of up to 3 digits) in the string so that I can put out a warning if there is any other quantity of numbers (especially no numbers at all or more than one)?

And how do I extract that number given that I don't know where it is in the string?

I've got this much from the tutorials I've read:

```
String needle = "\\d{1,}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(needle);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(haystack);

while(matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found at: "+ matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
}
```

This code tells me if the pattern matches multiple times but does so by writing a separate line for each match, I just want to know the number of matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex to find exactly one number in the text:

`[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*`

Explained:

```
[^0-9]*     match 0 or more non-digits at beginning of input
([0-9]+)    match 1 or more digits, and capture them
[^0-9]*     match 0 or more non-digits at end of input
```

You then use the [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) to match against the entire input.

The value and position of the captured number is available with the [`group(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-), [`start(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start-int-), and [`end(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end-int-) methods.

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("foo  tickets 456 ");
    test("42");
    test(" 1 A 3");
    test("4 tickets");
    test("billets 2");
}
public static void test(String haystack) {
    System.out.println(haystack);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*").matcher(haystack);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("  Needle was found in positions " + m.start(1) + " thru " + m.end(1));
        System.out.println("  Number from haystack is " + m.group(1)); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("  Haystack doesn't have exactly 1 needle");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
foo  tickets 456 
  Needle was found in positions 13 thru 16
  Number from haystack is 456
42
  Needle was found in positions 0 thru 2
  Number from haystack is 42
 1 A 3
  Haystack doesn't have exactly 1 needle
4 tickets
  Needle was found in positions 0 thru 1
  Number from haystack is 4
billets 2
  Needle was found in positions 8 thru 9
  Number from haystack is 2
```

Comment: There is just one minor problem: "SHOULD contain a number of 1 to 3 digits" it matches "654654 tickets" for example

Comment: @JorgeCampos *"For safety sake, I think my code should verify that there is just ONE number (**regardless of the number of digits in the number**)"* means that number of digits is not a strict requirement.

Comment: @Andreas You and Jorge are both right. I was inconsistent in my wording. I'm going to be very surprised if the number ever exceeds even two digits but I increased that to three to cover a case for an unusually large order. But it's probably best to be prepared for a (positive) number of even more digits.

Answer (score 1):

In order to extract information from a String you need to use regex groups

```
 String haystack = "123 Foo Fighters";

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^\d]*(\\d{1,3})[^\\d]*$");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(haystack);

 if(matcher.find()) {
     String number = matcher.group(1);
     System.out.println(number);
 }
```

Explanation

> ^ start
>   [^\d]* non digits (0 or more)
>   (\d{1,3}) match and capture from 1 to 3 digits
>   [^\d]* follows non digits (0 or more)
>   $ end

Comment: the description is a bit confuse
"the string SHOULD contain a number of 1 to 3 digits, a space, and a word or phrase of some kind"

but it is easy to fix

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it some more and came up with a solution that works. I'm not sure if this is the BEST solution to this problem - if you think of a better one, by all means reply with it - but here it is:

```
String haystack = "foo  tickets 456 ";
String needle = "\\d{1,}+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(needle);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(haystack);

int counter = 0;
int start = 0;
int end = 0; 
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Needle '" + needle + "' found in haystack '" + haystack + "' at: "+ matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
   start = matcher.start();
   end = matcher.end();
   counter++;
} 

switch (counter) {
case 1: 
    System.out.println("Needle was found in positions " + start + " thru " + end);
    String number = haystack.substring(start, end);
    System.out.println("Number from haystack is " + number); 
    break;
case 0:
    System.err.println("ERROR! Needle was not found in haystack!");
    break;
default: 
    System.err.println("ERROR: Needle was found in haystack " + counter + "   times!");     
}
```

I've tried several tests, including no numbers and multiple numbers, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Why not just `[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*`? If it [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--), there is exactly one number in the text, and you can get it by calling [`group(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-).